# How To Get Row Entries with Max Column in SQL, Please Help! :p

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a bit stuck on how to get all the rows I want from the max count of one column, grouping by only some specific columns. For example, over here I want to group by user and name so that they are always distinct. But for country and device type I only want the combination of their max event_ct to show up

| user | name | country | device | event_ct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Albert | US | Mac | 5 |
| 5 | Albert | GB | Phone | 7 |
| 5 | Albert | CN | Mac | 3 |
| 6 | Albert | CN | Mac | 1 |
| 7 | Laurel | US | Phone | 7 |

I want a mysql query to turn it into

| user | name | country | device |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Albert | GB | Phone |
| 6 | Albert | CN | Mac |
| 7 | Laurel | US | Phone |

Please help! Thanks :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Comment: I think it is a bit different. He just needs a distinct column (home) with the max of another column (resource). I need to have mines grouped by 2 column (user, name) but the 2 column combination (country, device) has to be the max of the event_ct.

Answer (score 0):

Although I still think this is a duplicate question but for the good measure.

you can use subquery in `where` clause:

```
select user,name,country,device from cte
where event_ct in (select max(event_ct) from cte group by user,name)
```

here is [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=98767b836c5b7f43e089181780a6c9b2) for better examine.

---

`group by` and `distinct` are fundamental same in some way, because you are telling SQL that you want **UNIQUE** row. `group by a,b` will give you distinct combination of a and b since it "GROUP" all the same (a,b) combination together.

---

### re-edit

in some case if you got more then one row with max `event_ct`
for example `user 5` got two row with `event_ct = 7`
you can add `distinct` to get rid of duplicate.